# How to build .net 6 project programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am trying to build a .net6.0 project programmatically using MSBuild but it is giving following error:

```
  Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.  S:\TEMP\Project1\Project1.csproj
  Source=Microsoft.Build
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate()
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.Initialize(ProjectRootElement xml, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String explicitToolsVersion, String explicitSubToolsetVersion, Int32 visualStudioVersionFromSolution, BuildParameters buildParameters, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContext, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId, Nullable`1 projectLoadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance..ctor(String projectFile)
   at ConsoleApp5.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Project1.csproj that is being compiled:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

With just an empty HelloWorld class stub

Here is calling Project File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AssemblyName>ConsoleApp5</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver" Version="5.11.0-rc.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Runtime" Version="17.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and the calling code:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Execution;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var project = new ProjectInstance(@"S:\TEMP\Project1\Project1.csproj");
            project.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why resolver is unable to resolve Microsoft.NET.Sdk and how to fix
   it
2. Is it possible to bundle SDK with my app so that the users may
   not need to install .net SDK separately?

Comment: What command did you execute? What is the output of `dotnet --info`?

Comment: Stupid question, but do you have dotnet 6 installed? If you do `dotnet --version` what do you get?

Comment: Simply using MSBuild assemblies might not be enough to setup a proper environment to actually compile `csproj` files. Take a look at [MSBuildLocator](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildLocator).